# Why AWS glue giving connection timeout error when connected to Redshift connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift cluster whos Publicly accessible option disabled.
I want to read the physical table from redshift then do some transformation and write back to different redshift table.
But I'm always getting error of time out as shown below:

```
AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 [glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/24.75.06.85, glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/22.210.001.155, glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/23.33.08.206, glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/24.194.008.134, glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/24.75.007.228, glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/24.229.003.246, glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/24.195.005.154, glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/23.248.001.228] failed: connect timed out
```

What should I do?

Comment: This looks like a VPC subnet setup issue. It is unclear where you are getting the error. You may need to provide more details.

Comment: Error come at glue job running